Angular content projection in standalone component
It is not rendering the @ContentChild in another standalone component.
Added stackblitz
HTML
<div class="card">
  <h6 class="card-header">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="cardHeader.tpl"></ng-container>
    @if (hasActions()) {
      <!-- <ng-content select="app-card-header-actions"> </ng-content> -->
    }
  </h6>
  <div class="card-body">
    @defer(when cardMainContent.tpl) {
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="cardMainContent.tpl"></ng-container>
    } @loading(minimum 750ms) {
      <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
      </div>
    } @placeholder() {
    <div class="my-5">
      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" role="alert">
        No Data Found!
      </div>
    </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>


TS
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCardHeader]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class CardHeaderDirective {
  constructor(public tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'app-card-header-actions',
  standalone: true,
})
export class CardHeaderActionsDirective {}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCardMainContent]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class CardContentDirective {
  constructor(public tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CardContentDirective, CardHeaderDirective],
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrl: '',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CardComponent {
  hasActions = input<boolean>(false);
  @ContentChild(CardContentDirective) cardMainContent!: CardContentDirective;
  @ContentChild(CardHeaderDirective) cardHeader!: CardHeaderDirective;
}


ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tpl')
at CardComponent_Template (card.component.html:3:19)

Content projection should work and it should display the content from different cards.

We cannot use a directive on ng-template since it does not fire, ng-template is a virtual element and is not rendered in the DOM, so the better option, is to just create template reference variables like #cardHeader and #cardMainContent and access these through ContentChild and directly render them on the HTML.
  @ContentChild('cardMainContent') cardMainContent!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('cardHeader') cardHeader!: TemplateRef<any>;

card.component.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  ContentChild,
  Directive,
  TemplateRef,
  inject,
  input,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'app-card-header-actions',
  standalone: true,
})
export class CardHeaderActionsDirective {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CardComponent {
  hasActions = input<boolean>(false);
  @ContentChild('cardMainContent') cardMainContent!: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('cardHeader') cardHeader!: TemplateRef<any>;
  barChartOptions = {};
}

card.component.html
<div class="card">
  <h6 class="card-header">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="cardHeader"></ng-container>
    @if (hasActions()) {
    <ng-content select="app-card-header-actions"> </ng-content>
    }
  </h6>
  <div class="card-body">
    @defer(when cardMainContent) {
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="cardMainContent"></ng-container>
    } @loading(minimum 750ms) {
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
    } @placeholder() {
    <div class="my-5">
      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" role="alert">
        No Data Found!
      </div>
    </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>

app.component.html
<mat-grid-list
  cols="4"
  gutterSize="15px"
  rowHeight="375px"
  id="dashboard-tiles"
>
  <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1" class="card shadow">
    <app-card>
      <ng-template #cardHeader>LOREM</ng-template>
      <ng-template #cardMainContent>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item btn-link">Item 1</li>
          <li class="list-group-item btn-link">Item 2</li>
          <li class="list-group-item btn-link">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </ng-template>
    </app-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>

  <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1" class="card shadow">
    <app-card [hasActions]="true">
      <ng-template #cardHeader>IPSUM</ng-template>

      <ng-template #cardMainContent>
        <ng-template
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="cardTitle"
          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ data: resData }"
        ></ng-template>
        <div class="card-body mt-0 p-0" [style.height.px]="400">
          <canvas
            baseChart
            [datasets]="[]"
            [labels]="[]"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [plugins]="[]"
            [legend]="true"
            [type]="'bar'"
          >
          </canvas>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </app-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>

<ng-template #cardTitle let-data="data">
  <div class="card-title">
    @if (data.length) {
    <!-- display-->
    } @else {
    <!-- some other display-->
    }
  </div>
</ng-template>

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing the same thing.
